# Значение слова "эксперт"?

Tags: значение-слов

> [ЭКСПЕРТ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82), -а; м. [от лат. expertus - опытный] Специалист, производящий экспертизу. Военный э. Судебный э. Э. по истории живописи. Привлечь к работе экспертов по разным вопросам. Высокая оценка экспертов. <Экспертный, -ая, -ое. Э-ая комиссия. Э-ые заключения.

Неужели только производящий экспертизу? А просто хорошего специалиста нельзя назвать экспертом? Что это за "Словарь иностранных слов русского языка"? Можно ли ему доверять?

> [ЭКСПЕРТ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lower/19412) — (лат. expertus). Знаток, специалист в известном деле: сведущий в чем либо человек. Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка. Чудинов А.Н., 1910. ЭКСПЕРТ лат. expertus, от experiri, исследовать. Знаток, выбранный для определения… …   Словарь иностранных слов русского языка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто хороший специалист - это знаток, а вот знаток, который даёт заключение при рассмотрении какого-либо вопроса, т.е. производящий исследование или тот, к кому обращаются за помощью в исследовании чего-то, - это эксперт. В бытовой ситуации Вы и не скажете, что это эксперт,  замените слово синонимом - опытный, знающий, сведущий человек, хороший специалист и т.д.

Иногда  используют термин для обозначения человека, которому можно доверить оценку деятельности других специалистов, но ведь это тоже своего рода экспертиза, поэтому мне кажется, оба определения имеют в виду одно и то же - тот, кто проводит экспертизу - и официальную, и неофициальную.